# Simulation of random points on a multivariate convex hull with scipy

Tags: python, scipy, simulation, convex-hull, scipy-spatial

I have a data with 10 000 rows and 10 columns. The first goal of my study is to calculate the "Convex Hull" on this data. The package "scipy" can do this easily and I can get the vertices, the parameters of the different hyperplanes such as : b0 + b1.x1 + b2.x2 + .... + b10.x10 = 0 where : (b0,b1,...,b10) are the parameters of one facet of the convex hull (I can know the vertices on it).

```
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull, convex_hull_plot_2d
import numpy as np
fit_hull = ConvexHull(data)
V = fit_hull.vertices
parameters = fit_hull.equations
```

My question is : how can I uniformly simulate : random points on the convex hull, knowing all of this ?

It is difficult because it is quite simple to simulate random points on a hyperplane, but here, it is a hyperplane bounded with the vertices of the facet (for example, with 3 variables : to create a facet, I need three points, so it would a triangle).

Thank you so much

Have a nice day (from France)

Answer (score 0):

- Make a Delaunay tessellation of your convex hull. In 2D these are triangles, in 3D these are tetrahedra, and you can get their area/volume.
- Pick a triangle/tetrahedron at random, with probabiities given by the normalized areas/volumes.
- Pick a point uniformly in this triangle/tetrahedron.